# How to make an element slide with the viewport as it scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I've Googled for this but must be using the wrong keywords.

Basically I want to use the effect that Magento and now Stack Overflow uses. That is, there is an element in a column, and when you scroll down, it *sticks* to the top of the viewport. And once scrolled up again, it goes back into the normal page flow.

This Ask A Question is a good page for example. Scroll down and watch the "How to Format" element come down (might need to make your viewport smaller if you have a large screen to see the effect).

I've noticed it is setting `position: fixed` in the CSS. The JavaScript however is obfuscated.

What's the easiest way to achieve this effect? Is there a jQuery plugin available?

Comment: I'd never noticed that behaviour on SO before...I must stop using the internet with my eyes closed... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that should help: http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed google doing this in certain places, like here http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en (the left side navigation bar). From what I can tell, they checking the position on the page and then setting the item to a fixed position once the page is scrolled down enough for the element to start scrolling off the screen.

It looks like the other method, using jQuery to set the top margin will allow the element to lag behind and get choppy (if you don't use animation) since the javascript must continue to position the element.

Here is an example in Ext, it would probably help a lot if I didn't have the select in the event handler, but it works.

```
Ext.fly(document).on("scroll", function(e,t,o){
    Ext.select(".pinnable").each(function(el,c,idx){
        var y = window.scrollY;
        if(!el.hasClass("pinned")){
            var ypos = el.getY();
            if(y>ypos){
                el.addClass("pinned");
                el.set({
                    originalY:ypos
                });
            }                   
        } else {
            var origy = el.getAttribute("originalY");
            if(origy && y<origy){
                el.removeClass("pinned")
            }
        }
    });     
});
```