# CSS Semi-fixed Element - follow-up question

Tags: css, scroll, fixed

This is a follow-on question from this thread:
[CSS Semi-fixed Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460364/css-semi-fixed-element)

I implemented kelso's solution and it works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome. However, IE 8 is not playing ball.

I have rolled the code out so that you can see the problem I am having on a live website: 
[Gran Via hotels](http://www.subwayhotels.com/Madrid/Gran-Via-hotels-930.html)

IE is listening for scroll events but is not moving the div as the user scrolls down the page. It seems as though the following line is not doing anything in IE:

```
d.css({ position: "fixed", top: "0px"   });
```

The first line is also evaluating to -2 in IE whereas in Firefox it's 377.

```
var scrollerTopMargin = $("#scroll-container").offset().top;
```

I am no CSS expert and have been pulling my hair out on this. There must be a simple solution! Please help!

Thanks
Ben

Comment: The fixed behaviour is weird, I cannot see all the footer because the sidebar is above..! I don't agree with this style.

Comment: It's weird because is not complete. It should stop at the footer too. I personally like it. Also I've seen it used in a number of sited.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not like your doctype and is running with quirks mode activated. this is why it does not work.

Try this one and see if it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks Alin, changing to that doctype works but validator.w3.org reports 402 page errors (page currently has two errors). 4.01 strict only gives 15 errors so going to go with that:

Comment: Thanks Alin, changing to that doctype works but validator.w3.org reports 402 errors (transitional HTML has 2 errors). Using 4.01 strict only gives 15 errors. When scrolling down page the div moves fine but when I scroll back to top of page the div covers the header because the "var scrollerTopMargin = $("#scroll-container").offset().top;" line is returning -2... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To run IE8 in standard mode you need to choose a strict doctype, not a a transitional one

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode